# css margin left, works in px but not in %

Tags: css, margin

anybody knows why this code doesnt work:

```
#interieur{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
}
```

and this one does

```
#interieur{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left:500px;
}
```

I'm working in PHP and the div "interieur" is inside an echo

Comment: Remove `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: What does not work? What is the expected behaviour and what is the observed behaviour?

Comment: I want the div to be in the middle of the screen but it statys in the very left, but when I try 500px instead of 50% it's working. I'm also trying in a non php page and it's working with 50%

Comment: @Mooseman it still doesn't work without it :(

Comment: It works for me with no changes. See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zZHRY/

(I added a border, width and height for demonstration purposes.) Are you sure there are no other styles conflicting with it?

Comment: thanks @ZakAngelle it also works for me in an html page but when my div "interieur" is inside a PHP code it doesn't work anymore, and it's weird because left:500px; is still working

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "inside a PHP code"?

Comment: @ZakAngelle
<?PHP
echo '<div id=\'interieur\'><img src= \'../test/images_membres/' . $_GET['image'] . '.jpg\' id=\'imageGrand\'></div>
?>

Comment: If you want it centered, use `left:50%;margin-left:-200px; /*Half the width*/`

Comment: It doesn't matter if the `<div>` is produced from PHP or not when you're talking about CSS. Only the output matters.

Comment: thanks @mooseman I know it doesnt matter if it's PHP or not, but still inside my echo it doesnt want to work

Comment: Is there any way you could link to a sample?

Comment: @Mooseman yes that's exactly what i'm doing to center it, in jquery :
$('#interieur').css('margin-left',-$('#imageGrand').width()/2);
but since it doesn't want to goes at 50% in the begining, now i can only see the half on the div in the very left

Comment: No need to use jQuery for that, unless the width is undefined in production. What problem(s) do you have?

Comment: @Mooseman it's undefined since the width of the div "interieur" will change every time the page will be call
my only problem is that my div "interieur" doesn't want to go at 50%

Comment: @ZakAngelle yep i put it there : http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/sG6yS/

Comment: You realize you don't need to echo all of that?  Just do `<div id="interieur"><img src="../test/images_membres/<?php echo $_GET['image']; ?>.jpg" alt="" id="imageGrand" /></div>` - Only echo the portion that's needed to be processed by PHP.

Comment: @Axel true but my problem remains the same

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you have forgotten to subtract half of your div width to the left position (think about it, if left would be 50% and right 50% too, your div would be 0% wide :)

You can use CSS3 Calc to achieve the result, knowing before the dimensions of your div:

```
#interieur{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left:calc(50% - 100px); /* 100px is half of your div width */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zZHRY/3/

Comment: thanks but what is inside my div is an image which will change, so i do substract the half but in jquery

Comment: This was the answer to the original question: "css margin left, works in px but not in %... anybody knows why this code doesnt work ?". Now you are asking something different, that should be a different question, imho

Answer (score -1):

If you can specify a width of your div, try this:

```
width: 500px; /* insert width here */
margin: 0 auto;
```